# How to combine two batch scripts, put them into one batch file and run them in descending order

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi I would like to take two batch scripts and combine them into " one ". I would also like the now " One " batch file to run in descending order.

I am able to use the `CALL` function however, I then have three batch files.

I am trying to combine them and achieve the same result as I would if I had to run batchA.bat and batchB.bat from the callbatchA+batchB.bat file

> e.g  callbatchA+B.batch, batchA.bat, batchB.bat

I tried a simple `concat` of the files by running concatfile.bat included below

```
copy callbatchA+B.bat+batchA.bat+batchB.bat combined_.bat
```

This did not work example of `concatenated` file below

```
    ::CallScript
    CALL C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\batchA.bat
    CALL C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\BatchB.bat
    ::ScriptA
    @echo off 
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    CD "C:\deviceno\"

    ::only change these three lines
    set "start=295"  ::starts from this number
    set "amount=10" ::amount of files created
    set "length=5" :: 

    set /a "last=%start%+%amount%"
    for /l %%i in (%start%,1,%last%) do (
    set "folderName=0000000000%%i"
    set "folderName=!folderName:~-%length%!"
    md "!folderName!"
    )
    pausefor  
    ::ScriptB
    /D  %%a  in ("C:\deviceno\*.*") do xcopy  /y  /d  C:\Source\*.*"%%a\"
```

I tried to edit the code with `goto :eof` such as below but I have had no luck so far.

```
::ScriptA
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD "C:\device_numbers\"

::only change these three lines
set "start=295"  ::starts from this number
set "amount=10" ::amount of files created
set "length=5" :: 

set /a "last=%start%+%amount%"
for /l %%i in (%start%,1,%last%) do (
set "folderName=0000000000%%i"
set "folderName=!folderName:~-%length%!"
md "!folderName!"
) DO CALL ::ScriptB

::ScriptB
p /D  %%a  in ("C:\device_numbers\*.*") do xcopy  /y  /d   C:\Source\*.*"%%a\"
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
::CallScript
@echo off
CALL :ScriptA
CALL :ScriptB
pause
goto :eof

:ScriptA
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD "C:\deviceno\"

::only change these three lines
set "start=295"  ::starts from this number
set "amount=10" ::amount of files created
set "length=5" ::length of fileNames

set /a "last=%start%+%amount%"
for /l %%i in (%start%,1,%last%) do (
set "folderName=0000000000%%i"
set "folderName=!folderName:~-%length%!"
md "!folderName!"
)
goto :eof

:ScriptB
for /D %%a in ("C:\deviceno\*.*") do xcopy /y /d "C:\Source\*.*" "%%a\"
goto :eof
```

This would be one file, using subroutines for the file creation and the copying.

I would suggest looking at [this](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) for a better understanding of how calling labels works

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```dos
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL

:: set up some data items for demo

SET /a fred=3
SET /a joe=8
SET /a charlie=10

CALL external add result %fred% %charlie%
ECHO %result%
CALL external add result %fred% %charlie% %joe%
ECHO %result%
CALL external subtract result %fred% %charlie%
ECHO %result%
CALL external concatenate result %fred% xyz %charlie%
ECHO %result%

GOTO :EOF
```

**external.bat**

```
:: @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto %*

:add
shift
set $=%1&shift
set /a $t=0
:addloop
set /a $t+=%1
shift
if "%1" neq "" goto addloop
:commonexit
endlocal&set %$%=%$t%
goto :eof

:subtract
shift
set $=%1&shift
set /a $t=%1-%2
goto commonexit

:concatenate
shift
set $=%1&shift
set "$t="
:concatloop
set "$t=%$t%%1"
shift
if "%1" neq "" goto concatloop
goto commonexit
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean this?

Run `batchA.bat` and pipe `batchA.bat` output to `batchB.bat` and then run `batchB.bat`

```
batchA | batchB
```

or run `batchA.bat` and then run `batchB.bat`

```
batchA & batchB
```